# Maven can't find some dependencies' components

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, intellij-plugin

I'm making a plugin for Intellij IDEA. I tried to build and compile my project with maven and have some problems with com.intellij open sources. Here is my pom.xml dependencies:

```
     <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <org.apache.maven.plugins.compiler.version>3.5</org.apache.maven.plugins.compiler.version>
        <intellij.openapi.version>7.0.3</intellij.openapi.version>
        <intellij.annotations.version>12.0</intellij.annotations.version>
        <intellij.forms_rt.version>7.0.3</intellij.forms_rt.version>
        <intellij.openapi.version>7.0.3</intellij.openapi.version>
        <intellij.extensions.version>7.0.3</intellij.extensions.version>
        <intellij.java2c.version>7.0.3</intellij.java2c.version>
    </properties>
    </dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi</artifactId>
            <version>${intellij.openapi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${intellij.annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms_rt</artifactId>
            <version>${intellij.forms_rt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${intellij.extensions.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>javac2</artifactId>
            <version>${intellij.java2c.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And here is what I've got when I'm trying to compile or build the project:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[6,40] package com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl does not exist
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[11,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ToolWindowFactory
  location: package com.intellij.openapi.wm
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[13,34] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JBList
  location: package com.intellij.ui.components
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[34,50] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class ToolWindowFactory
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[42,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JBList
  location: class com.company.ap.gigaspaces.plugin.PrimaryToolWindowFactory
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[362,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EditorHeaderComponent
  location: class com.company.ap.gigaspaces.plugin.PrimaryToolWindowFactory
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[79,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SERVICE
  location: interface com.intellij.ui.content.ContentFactory
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[58,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[263,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EditorHeaderComponent
  location: class com.company.ap.gigaspaces.plugin.PrimaryToolWindowFactory
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[363,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EditorHeaderComponent
  location: class com.company.ap.gigaspaces.plugin.PrimaryToolWindowFactory
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[363,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EditorHeaderComponent
  location: class com.company.ap.gigaspaces.plugin.PrimaryToolWindowFactory
```

**UPDATE:** I added two more dependencies and now I've got only 1 error left, which I can't solve.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.adedayo.intellij.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-impl</artifactId>
        <version>142.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.adedayo.intellij.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-api</artifactId>
        <version>142.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The following error:

```
[ERROR] /home/student/Dev/gs-idea-plugin/main/java/com/company/ap/gigaspaces/plugin/PrimaryToolWindowFactory.java:[79,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable SERVICE
[ERROR] location: interface com.intellij.ui.content.ContentFactory
```

I opened the location of the interface and there is no such variable but the class called SERVICE with just one static method. Could it be maven've got sick and tried to find variable which is class?

Comment: The jar files are getting downloaded? Did you check the repository?

Comment: Which one repository?

Comment: Either you didn't add Gigaspaces to your dependencies OR you have the wrong version.  Are you sure it's available in Maven Central?  Not all JARs are. I see Mule is available, but not Gigaspaces.  I thought that was a licensed product.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted gigaspaces dependencies because in that case it was "too much code" and I can't create the question. Anyway, I added two more dependencies and 1 error left: cannot find symbol variable  
location: interface com.intellij.ui.content.ContentFactory

Comment: Is there any way I can create dependency from my local repository to include the last one?

Comment: I can see this missing interface in the libs I added through pom dependencies, why doesn't maven see it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved the issue by creating dependencies locally. Maven central has too old versions of required intellij libs, so I found the script, which is installing all files in IntelliJ IDEA's lib/ folder to the local maven .m2 repository. I copied from here: [github](https://github.com/forge/intellij-idea-plugin/blob/master/install-intellij-libs.sh) Then created pom.xml file just like in this repository and imported dependencies from the idea version which I have on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The log suggests that Maven managed to resolve your dependencies (otherwise, it wouldn't even have called the compiler).

You need to fix your java classes as they are the ones with compilation problems (are all imports included in your classes?).

Comment: My java classes are just fine and plugin compiles without errors. I included this package com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl to pom dependencies and the exect error is gone. What about the others?